# Where can I find a library to read/write Analyze v 7.5 images in C#?

Tags: c#

As the question asks:  I've to a bunch of images that I need to be able to both read and write using the [Analyze 7.5 image format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyze_%28imaging_software%29).  Using search terms like 'analyze image' causes my google-fu to fail, hence asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer:  If there is one, it's very hard to find.  I could either roll my own from @Charlie's links, or just use C++ and itk (or many other libraries out there).

Answer (score 0):

There's some information that might be useful on this page about the [Bioelectromagnetism Matlab Toolbox](http://eeg.sourceforge.net/).